# Obtaining (significantly) inaccurate values when using Numpy linalg.lstsq to solve a linear system

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, physics

I'm attempting to use `Numpy`'s `linalg.lstsq()` to follow the line of logic in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1642768/822508) post. I'll repeat it here.

---

Suppose I have four microphones in 3-dimensional space (or light receivers, etc). I'd like to use the difference in time between each microphone registering a gun shot, or otherwise the time of arrival at each microphone, to determine the coordinates of the shooter. So, we know the coordinates of the four microphones `x_i, y_i`, and the velocity `v` of the sound. We do *not* know the coordinates of the shooter, nor the time the shot was fired.

For each microphone, we write:

`(X-x_i)**2 + (Y-y_i)**2 + (Z-z_i)**2 = (v(t_i - T))**2`

Where `X,Y,Z` are the shooter's coordinates, and `T` is the time of the shot.

The problem can be simplified if we consider all the `i/j` possibilities, subtrating equation `i` from equation `j`. We end up with `6` equations (in general, given `n` microphones, `n(n-1)/2` equations) of the form:

`2*(x_j - x_i)*X + 2*(y_j - y_i)*Y + 2*(z_j - z_i)*Z + 2 * v**2 * (t_i - t_j) = 2 * v**2 ( t_i**2 - t_j**2) + (x_j**2 + y_j**2 + z_j**2) - (x_i**2 + y_i**2 + z_i**2)`

These equations are of the form `Xv_1 + Y_v2 + Z_v3 + T_v4 = b`, where `v_i` are vectors. We (should) then be able to use a linear least-squares fit to "solve" (or, at least, get a rough estimate of) `X,Y,Z` and, as a byproduct, `T`.

---

I've tried *alot* of different approaches to this problem, and all signs point toward using the method described in the linked post (i.e., solving this by linear least-squares, then using this "solution" as an initial estimate for a more "precise" algorithm). So, I wrote the following (admittedly, somewhat rough) `Python` code to get started. It solves the linear least-squares portion of the problem:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from numpy import *
from random import randrange

@dataclass
class Vertexer:

    @staticmethod
    def find():

        # Pick microphones to be at random locations
        x_1 = randrange(10); y_1 = randrange(10); z_1 = randrange(10)
        x_2 = randrange(10); y_2 = randrange(10); z_2 = randrange(10)
        x_3 = randrange(10); y_3 = randrange(10); z_3 = randrange(10)
        x_4 = randrange(10); y_4 = randrange(10); z_4 = randrange(10)

        # Pick shooter to be at random location
        x = randrange(100); y = randrange(100); z = randrange(100)

        # Set velocity (ok, it's a ray gun...)
        c = 299792 # km/s

        # Generate simulated source
        t_1 = math.sqrt( (x - x_1)**2 + (y - y_1)**2 + (z - z_1)**2 ) / c
        t_2 = math.sqrt( (x - x_2)**2 + (y - y_2)**2 + (z - z_2)**2 ) / c
        t_3 = math.sqrt( (x - x_3)**2 + (y - y_3)**2 + (z - z_3)**2 ) / c
        t_4 = math.sqrt( (x - x_4)**2 + (y - y_4)**2 + (z - z_4)**2 ) / c


        A = array([[2 * (x_1 - x_2), 2 * (y_1 - y_2), 2 * (z_1 - z_2), 2 * c * c * (t_2 - t_1)],
                   [2 * (x_1 - x_3), 2 * (y_1 - y_3), 2 * (z_1 - z_3), 2 * c * c * (t_3 - t_1)],
                   [2 * (x_1 - x_4), 2 * (y_1 - y_4), 2 * (z_1 - z_4), 2 * c * c * (t_4 - t_1)],
                   [2 * (x_2 - x_3), 2 * (y_2 - y_3), 2 * (z_2 - z_3), 2 * c * c * (t_3 - t_2)],
                   [2 * (x_2 - x_4), 2 * (y_2 - y_4), 2 * (z_2 - z_4), 2 * c * c * (t_4 - t_2)],
                   [2 * (x_3 - x_4), 2 * (y_3 - y_4), 2 * (z_3 - z_4), 2 * c * c * (t_4 - t_3)]
                   ])
        b = array([2 * c * c * (t_2 * t_2 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2),
                   2 * c * c * (t_3 * t_3 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3),
                   2 * c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4),
                   2 * c * c * (t_3 * t_3 - t_2 * t_2) + (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2) - (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3),
                   2 * c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_2 * t_2) + (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4),
                   2 * c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_3 * t_3) + (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4)])

        solved, residuals, rank, s = linalg.lstsq(A, b)

        print(solved)


myVertexer = Vertexer()

myVertexer.find()
```

Unfortunately, however, it does not seem to be producing very reasonable estimates. You can run the code for yourself, if you like, or here is a collection of runs comparing the found values to the coordinates of the "simulated" sources the algorithm produces.

```
Predicted: [ 2.26739519e+00  4.80191502e+00 -5.07181020e+00 ]
Actual:    78 35 57

Predicted: [ 7.72173135e-01 -2.61250803e+00  4.10306750e+00 ]
Actual:    30 75 48

Predicted: [-1.65368110e+00  8.82919123e-01  1.43648336e+00 ]
Actual:    67 56 44

Predicted: [ 4.08698715e+00 -3.19377148e-01  8.81706364e-01 ]
Actual:    9 82 13
```

Admittedly, I'm not sure what sort of precision to expect out of the initial least-squares solution. However, these values don't seem very nice to me. Where have I erred?

Please, let me know if I can offer any further clarifications.

> Note that I'm aware there are other methods to solving this problem (notably, a pretty good solution can be obtained by simply plugging into one of a number of packages with nonlinear solvers out there). I'm interested in determining why *this* solution (which I know the linked poster has used successfully, as have several others) is not working, both out of curiosity, and also because I'd like to take this further, where "custom" code will be useful.

Comment: Suggestion: set a random seed before you proceed

Comment: What happens when you set velocity to a smaller value? Say 300?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the suggestion. When I set the value to `300` precisely, I get similar results (for example, `Predicted: [-0.29188919  3.91470464 -2.01174068 ]
 Actual : 72 56 90`. Same for even smaller values (100, 30, 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues:

1. there is an error in the subtraction equation you refer to in the original post: on the RHS it should be `c * c * (t_i * t_i - t_j * t_j)` instead of `2 * c * c * (t_i * t_i - t_j * t_j)`.
2. the second problem is that in matrix `A` you have a column for `tau` (the fourth column) whereas in your calculation of `t_1` to `t_4` you implicitly assumed that `tau=0`, so you **cannot** have it as a variable in matrix `A`; hence the fourth column needs to be removed.

The revised code is as follows:

```
from random import randrange, seed
from numpy import array, linalg, set_printoptions
from dataclasses import dataclass
set_printoptions(suppress=True, linewidth=1000, precision=6)
seed(5)

@dataclass
class Vertexer:

    @staticmethod
    def find():

        # Pick microphones to be at random locations
        x_1 = randrange(10); y_1 = randrange(10); z_1 = randrange(10)
        x_2 = randrange(10); y_2 = randrange(10); z_2 = randrange(10)
        x_3 = randrange(10); y_3 = randrange(10); z_3 = randrange(10)
        x_4 = randrange(10); y_4 = randrange(10); z_4 = randrange(10)

        # Pick shooter to be at random location
        x = randrange(100); y = randrange(100); z = randrange(100)

        # Set velocity (ok, it's a ray gun...)
        c = 299792 # km/ns

        # Generate simulated source
        t_1 = math.sqrt( (x - x_1)**2 + (y - y_1)**2 + (z - z_1)**2 ) / c
        t_2 = math.sqrt( (x - x_2)**2 + (y - y_2)**2 + (z - z_2)**2 ) / c
        t_3 = math.sqrt( (x - x_3)**2 + (y - y_3)**2 + (z - z_3)**2 ) / c
        t_4 = math.sqrt( (x - x_4)**2 + (y - y_4)**2 + (z - z_4)**2 ) / c

        A = array([[2 * (x_1 - x_2), 2 * (y_1 - y_2), 2 * (z_1 - z_2)],
                   [2 * (x_1 - x_3), 2 * (y_1 - y_3), 2 * (z_1 - z_3)],
                   [2 * (x_1 - x_4), 2 * (y_1 - y_4), 2 * (z_1 - z_4)],
                   [2 * (x_2 - x_3), 2 * (y_2 - y_3), 2 * (z_2 - z_3)],
                   [2 * (x_2 - x_4), 2 * (y_2 - y_4), 2 * (z_2 - z_4)],
                   [2 * (x_3 - x_4), 2 * (y_3 - y_4), 2 * (z_3 - z_4)]
                   ])
        b = array([1 * c * c * (t_2 * t_2 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2),
                   1 * c * c * (t_3 * t_3 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3),
                   1 * c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_1 * t_1) + (x_1 * x_1 + y_1 * y_1 + z_1 * z_1) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4),
                   1 * c * c * (t_3 * t_3 - t_2 * t_2) + (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2) - (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3),
                   1 * c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_2 * t_2) + (x_2 * x_2 + y_2 * y_2 + z_2 * z_2) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4),
                   1 * c * c * (t_4 * t_4 - t_3 * t_3) + (x_3 * x_3 + y_3 * y_3 + z_3 * z_3) - (x_4 * x_4 + y_4 * y_4 + z_4 * z_4)])

        solved, residuals, rank, s = linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)

        print('Actual:', [x, y, z])
        print('Predicted:', solved)

myVertexer = Vertexer()

myVertexer.find()
```

And the output is:

```
Actual: [31, 48, 69]
Predicted: [31. 48. 69.]
```